# Multiplication/Cayley tables for the Dihedral Groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, dihedral-groups, cayley-table

I am currently doing a group theory problem, which asks for the multiplication table of the dihedral group $D_4$. Having looked up the answer online, I do not understand how some of the elements arose. For example, the elements on the columns and rows are $e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3$. I understand how those elements came about, but I don't understand why e.g. $ab,a^2b,a^3b$ are not considered here.  Can anyone help?

Comment: In the dihedral groups, $ab=ba^3$, so you are already considering it.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: Here $a$ is a rotation and $b$ is a flip.

Comment: It would help to know how you define the dihedral group.

Comment: Do both operations: assuming you perform them right to left, $ab$ will first reflect and then rotate; $ba^3$ will first rotate three times, then reflect. Figure out what that does to the square, and verify they are the exact same thing. I’m assuming you defined the dihedral group as the rigid motions of the square, or in terms of specific permutations.

Comment: Thank you - I'll consider it in a more geometrical way:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing, implicitly, is expressing the group $D_4$ with a presentation. A presentation of a group is made of two parts: a set of **generators**, and a set of **relations**.

Generators are commonly denoted with lowercase letters: $a,b,c,...$

Relations are expressions that generators satisfy: for instance, normally you have some relations with a single generator $a^4=e$, $b^2=e$, etc. , and then relations that tell you how the generators combine, such as $ab=ba$ (commutativity), or more complex ones like $ab=cba$.

Given a presentation, it is not easy in general to understand what group you are looking at: this is because the group is defined as all **words** in the generators (think $abba$) modulo the relations (meaning that if $ab=ba$, $abba=abab=baba$ etc.). So... you can have words that look different, but are actually the same when you apply the relations.

In your case, $D_4$ is given by $$\langle a,b \; |\; a^4=b^2=e, ab=ba^{-1} \text{ (or } b^{-1}ab=a^{-1})\rangle $$

So, for example:

$$ab = ba^{-1} = ba^3$$
$$a^2b = a(ba^{-1}) = ba^{-1}a^{-1} = ba^2$$

and, in general, whatever expression you consider can be reduced to one of the eight elements given by your book.

Comment: Excellent, that really helps! Thanks!